# Можно ли для работы сайта подгружать данные не с сервера, а из своей папки (предварительно скачав туда данные)?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, браузер, плагин

Суть в том, чтобы подгружать данные не по факту востребования, когда на сайте нужно их использовать и тогда запускается загрузка (ждать надо, пока всё загрузится), а заранее чтобы пользователь мог скачать предварительно данные с сайта (на определённой странице сайта, например, в личном кабинете), а когда для работы на сайте они понадобятся, то они сразу берутся из папки на компе пользователя (таким образом, ждать ничего не надо, данные сразу берутся в работу сайта).
Возможно ли такое? Может плагин можно написать? Или средствами js?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы не можете ничего записать в файловую систему пользователя. Но можете заранее получить с сервера любые данные и держать их в оперативной памяти, либо записать в какое либо локальное хранилище, такое как localStorage, indexedDB, WebSQL. И данные в любое из этих хранилищ вы пишите сами, средствами JS. Кроме того не забывайте что есть обычное кеширование браузером и если вы обращаетесь к какому либо файлу то он сохраняется у пользователя (при соответствующих настройках в заголовках и способах запроса)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответ. Я и написала, что пользователь, в личном кабинете например, нажимает кнопку Скачать данные. Качает куда-то себе в папку, сам выбирает в какую. А в настройках личного кабинете указывает эту папку. Затем, при работе сайта, когда данные эти понадобятся, js обращается к указанной пользователем в лк папке и берёт оттуда уже заранее скачанные файлы. Как-то так возможно?

Comment: @Mike Про кеш помню, но тут как раз большие (десятки мегабайт) данные надо загрузить и тут же ими оперировать, но «тут же» не получится, т.к. интернет не за доли секунды будет качать такой вес. Поэтому и ищу иное решение.
Речь идёт о 3д моделях, картинках большого разрешения, поэтому, так понимаю, localStorage, indexedDB, WebSQL не подходят…

Comment: Других способов все равно нет. Может конечно под какой нибудь конкретный браузер (читай хром) есть что то сделанное для расширений и можно сделать расширение, которое это делает. Но это надо поизучать какие сейчас возможности дают расширениям